# Find string after last underscore before dot extension

Tags: java, regex

I need to find `20140809T0000Z` in this string:

```
PREVIMER_F2-MARS3D-MENOR1200_20140809T0000Z.nc
```

I tried the following to keep the string before the `.nc`:

```
(?<=_)(.*)(?=.nc)
```

I have the following to start from the last underscore:

```
/_[^_]*$/
```

How can I find string after last underscore before dot extension, using a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx is not always the best solution... :)

```
String pattern="PREVIMER_F2-MARS3D-MENOR1200_20140809T0000Z.nc";
int start=pattern.lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
int end=pattern.lastIndexOf(".");
if(start != 0 && end != -1 && end > start) {
     System.out.println(pattern.substring(start,end);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below regex,

```
(?<=_)[^_]*(?=\.nc)
```

In your pattern just replace `.*` with `[^_]*` so that it would match the inner string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dS6wN0/1)

```
String s = "PREVIMER_F2-MARS3D-MENOR1200_20140809T0000Z.nc";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)[^_]*(?=\\.nc)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
 String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
 System.out.println(ResultString);
 } //=> 20140809T0000Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need lookahead for this requirement.

You can use:

```
[^._]+(?=[^_]*$)

// matches and returns 20140809T0000Z
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cW2nC8/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simpler pattern with a capturing group

```
.*_(.*)\.nc
```

By default the first `.*` will be "greedy" and consume as many characters as possible before the `_`, leaving just the desired string inside the `(.*)`.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aI2xQ9/1

Java code:

```
String input = "PREVIMER_F2-MARS3D-MENOR1200_20140809T0000Z.nc";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*_(.*)\\.nc");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
   String group = matcher.group(1);
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you need a sequence of non-underscore characters that immediately precede the period character.

Try `[^_.]+(?=\.)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sLAnVs/2

Thanks to [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) for pointing out that "no need to escape a period in a character class".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the comment, I was not aware of this. I've updated the answer.